# Disable multiple day selection to trigger a function in dayClick

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar in a site I'm building and I need to pop up a menu (much like context menu) when a user click on a day.

I'm currently using dayClick to trigger the context menu, and it show the menu with no problem. Problem arise when I want to execute the command in the context menu. The function the context-menu called is applied to all the day I've selected before (even though it's not highlighted), not just to 1 specific day I wanted or currently selected.

Case: I click on 12-04-2015, a context menu appear. Do nothing and click on another date 25-04-2015, context-menu appear and I click one of the command in it, which will assign the day cell with a class that change the background to certain color. Background changed. However, it's not limited to 25-04-2015 (the last day I clicked) but also to 12-04-2015, even though it's not highligthed or selected currently. And now I have changed 2 days, even though I was only supposed to change one.

This is the function I called in dayClick.

`execContextMenuDay(date, elem);`

`date` is the date currently selected `elem` is the `<td>` of the date that is currently selected.

I get the element by searching the table like this:

`var elem = $('.fc').find('.fc-day[data-date=' + date+ ']');`

This is the function content:

```
function execContextMenuDay(date, elem){
    elem.addClass('red');
}
```

which changes the background of the selected day to red.

I've tried setting the selectable option to false, but it's not working.

Does anyone know how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: have you tried this link http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/

Comment: yes, i've checked that out. well, if i write it that way, it works okay, because the command (ie. change background to red is executed when one click the day.

however, i need to show the context menu first, so in dayClick I call the context menu function, which will then if one of the command in there is clicked, will execute the another function (ie. change background).

Comment: and when i do that, fullcalendar seems to keep the cell i've clicked (but not doing anything with context menu) listed somewhere and when i click on another day and execute the context-menu command, all the cells i've clicked before including the one currently selected got changed too.

Comment: If you want to increase your chances of getting an answer, make a JSFiddle reproducing the problem. It's a bit complex to describe in just words.

Comment: i'd love to give the jsfiddle, but the code is a bit messy since i've been fiddling in it and i haven't had the time to sort out the code.... maybe later today...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself a few hour after posting this...

- Set a global variable (ie. selectedDay) to store the date currently clicked in the calendar.
- Replace it whenever i click another day
- And then, before executing the context-menu actions, check if the day currently click is the same with the one I store in that global variable
- If it's the same, execute action.

I hope there's some way to do this without having to have a global variable, but I guess for now this will do... It still doesn't 'disable' the multiple selection, but at least it will only execute action for the date currently clicked and not all the ones that have been clicked.